# Recuperar tiempo de respuesta de una peticion web dentro de un catch

Tags: c#

Antes de nada, gracias por la ayuda que me podáis prestar.

Vale, primero, disculpad mi pocos conocimientos, estoy aprendiendo, así que perdonad mi ignorancia.

Tengo un método  que llama a un servicio, y se supone que si se recibe alguna respuesta distinta del rango de 200, se va al catch. Pues bien, necesito, dentro de ese catch, recuperar de la cabecera (o de algún sitio) de esa respuesta el tiempo que ha tardado el servicio en responder.

No puedo usar timer ni cosas así (fue lo que primero en lo que pensé).

La cosa es que no se como recuperar de la exepcion este dato.

Muchas gracias!

````
        {
            try
            {
                // Reading the http response
                using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                 
                   /////   Llamada al endpoint

                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                  //// Aquí necesito recuperar el tiempo que ha tardado el servicio en responder (con el error)
            }
            return response;
        } ```
````

Comment: porque no podes usar timer? se usa el stopWatch para medir tiempos

Comment: esto es algo que me han pedido en mi nueva empresa, y esas son las especificaciones que me han dado. Imagino que es por que NO queremos tener en cuenta el tiempo que tarde el método en llegar al otro lado, solo el tiempo desde que se inicia el servicio hasta que responde

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo la siguiente solución

```
try
{
    var tiempoInicial = Datetime.Now;
    using(....)
    {
        //Tu código 
    }
}
catch(....)
{
    var tiempoFinal = DateTime.Now;
    var tiempoTranscurrido = tiempoFinal - tiempoInicial;
}
```

Bueno aquí lo que se hace es que antes de crear el objeto HttpWebResponse se guarda en una variable la hora de ese momento, te aclaro que este tiempo lo puedes obtener en la parte del código que más te convenga. Posteriormente si se produce la excepción se guarda en otra variable la hora de ese momento, entonces se resta con el tiempoInicial previamente guardado, esta diferencia de tiempos tiene el formato de horas:minutos:segundos:milisegundos, Si quisieras después esta diferencia la podrías mostrar mediante un mensaje o lo que desees, de esta forma vas a saber el tiempo transcurrido con una exactitud increíble

Comment: Esto es lo que yo plantee en el trabajo, pero me dijeron que no querian poner este tipo de cosas en elcódigo... de todas formas te doy un voto, porque esto funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 1):

Yo voy a responder mi pregunta con otra solución:

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
try
{   
    var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream answer = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            // do something
            watch.Stop(); 
            Console.WriteLine($"Success at {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException e) 
{
    // If we got here, it was a timeout exception.
    watch.Stop(); 
    Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred at {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} \n {e}"); 
}
```

Creo que el watch es ideal para esto.